# Fuzziness Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

fromSimilarity method is not supporting for Elastic Saecrh 2.4

```
 QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery(IdxSchemaConstants.ENTITY_NAME_SUGGEST, input.toLowerCase()).fuzziness(Fuzziness.fromSimilarity(0.6f));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: Fuzziness.fromSimilarity(0.6f) how to write this part in elastic search 2.4 i have to replace a certain piece of code  from elastic search 1.4.3 to elasticsearch 2.4